# Unix replace special characters from the file

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file which is as below:

```
["2015.01.07 10:06:24 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:34 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:48 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231528'>job_1418436639844_231528</a>","PigLatin:agg_daily_total_searches_and_unique_searc","data_svc","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","0","0"],
["2015.01.07 10:06:28 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:35 UTC","2015.01.07 10:13:28 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231529'>job_1418436639844_231529</a>","EndorsementsPendingImpressionEvent-c1201ed1-fb23-4","kafkaetl","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","1","1"],
```

I need to remove `[` and `],` from the start and end of each line respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below sed command.

```
sed 's/^\[\|\],$//g' file
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start of a line and `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line. Since basic sed uses BRE(Basic regular expressions), you need to escape the `|` symbol inorder to act like a logical OR operator.

Example:

```
$ cat ri
["2015.01.07 10:06:24 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:34 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:48 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231528'>job_1418436639844_231528</a>","PigLatin:agg_daily_total_searches_and_unique_searc","data_svc","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","0","0"],
["2015.01.07 10:06:28 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:35 UTC","2015.01.07 10:13:28 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231529'>job_1418436639844_231529</a>","EndorsementsPendingImpressionEvent-c1201ed1-fb23-4","kafkaetl","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","1","1"],
$ sed 's/^\[\|\],$//g' ri
"2015.01.07 10:06:24 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:34 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:48 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231528'>job_1418436639844_231528</a>","PigLatin:agg_daily_total_searches_and_unique_searc","data_svc","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","0","0"
"2015.01.07 10:06:28 UTC","2015.01.07 10:06:35 UTC","2015.01.07 10:13:28 UTC","<a href='/jobhistory/job/job_1418436639844_231529'>job_1418436639844_231529</a>","EndorsementsPendingImpressionEvent-c1201ed1-fb23-4","kafkaetl","marathon","SUCCEEDED","1","1","1","1"
```

Comment: You may needs `sed 's/^\[//;s/\],$/,/' file` because you are deleting last `,`

Comment: yep, op don't want the trailing `],` (including the comma)

Comment: :/ I thought it was the part of sentence not what he wants to delete :P suggested an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -d '[]' < file > new_file
```

Comment: and what if there are more `[` or `]` in the line?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^ *\[\(.*\)] *$/\1/' YourFile
```

keep everything inside external bracket, if no external bracket stay the same